# Is there any plugin for RCS in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rcs

Is there any plugin for RCS in Jenkins so that whenever any code change done in RCS should trigger a build in Jenkins

Comment: RCS and CVS use the same file format for their archive files; you might be able to make do with a CVS plugin. Or, as Larry suggests, you could migrate to a more modern VCS. An interesting bit of trivia: the RCS sources are [maintained in a Git repository](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/rcs.git/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no plugin. You can write the plugin yourself, or spend the time migrating to a newer VCS system.